# Pass Queryset list to javascript function with date time field

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime

With a query set from my django model, I would like to print a LineChart using Google Chart with date time in X values.

The date time in javascript need to be in this format :

```
new Date(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE)
```

I need to pass a list like this one to Google Chart:

```
data.addRows([
    [new Date(2000, 8, 5), 1200],
    [new Date(2001, 8, 5), 1223],
    [new Date(2002, 8, 5), 1240]
]
```

In my django views.py file, I am doing this :

```
def Function(request, page_id):

    query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(page__pk=page_id)

    list_impressions = query_set.values_list('created_at', 'page_impressions')
    context = {'impressions': list_impressions}

    return render(request, 'datacenter/facebook/impressions.html', context)
```

In my django template,

```
{% for record in impressions %}
    {{ record }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get :

```
(datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 8, 17, 49, 732016, tzinfo=<UTC>), 219482)
(datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 8, 52, 11, 912992, tzinfo=<UTC>), 219482)
```

But I need to pass to javascript :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [new Date(2017, 2, 1, 8, 17, 49), 1200],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 1, 8, 52, 11), 1223]
);
```

Where should I make the link between the representation of date time in Django and Javascript ? Views, template ?

I tried to use many other questions in stack overflow with no success. I also tried to build ugly things as creating a list of strings and then transform it in the template.

Comment: You could provide a view that responds with a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) with the json serialized data. Then in your javascript you can fetch the data from this url with an ajax request and deserialize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that in javascript as following. For Eg: if you get the datetime value with any key called temp_datetime then use that as following to convert to javascript date object.
`new Date("{{ temp_datetime|date:"Y, m, d, H, i, s" }}")` in this way you can convert your datetime to javascript Date object.

Comment: I got a list of [date, value]. I would like to avoid to transform the list in the view and/or template.

Comment: I am trying to use your solution, but after the template load, i got this format : [new Date(mer, 01 Fév 2017 08:17:49), 219482]

Comment: Almost, i got this : [new Date("2017, 02, 01, 08, 17, 49"), 219482], so I did this : [new Date({{ row.0|date:"Y, m, d, H, i, s" }}), {{ row.1 }}], but it doesn't work cause the google loader.js load with row.0 before the transformation.

Comment: Create an empty array and parse your values in that and then pass the 
`my_list = [];
{% for i in list_impressions%}my_list.push([new Date({{ row.0|date:"Y, m, d, H, i, s" }}), {{ row.1 }}]){% endfor %}
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(my_list);`

Comment: I had just to add a header by initializing : my_list = [['date', 'impressions']]; and then it worked. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's Date class can accept a value in ISO format directly. So you can output the dates in that format and pass them into the constructor.

You could do this directly in the template:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    {% for row in list_impressions %}[new Date("{{ row.0.isoformat }}"), {{ row.1 }}]{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
);
```

although it might be clearer if you do more in the view.

Comment: I did it and now i get this error message : "at least one digit most occur after a decimal point". Here is the javascript :
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
            [new Date(2017-02-01T08:17:49.732016+00:00), 219482],[new Date(2017-02-01T08:52:11.912992+00:00), 219482]
        );

Comment: what do you think of transforming the date time in epoch directly in the view ?

Comment: Sorry, should have had some quotes around the timestamp.